# How do I take multiple input's from user and and write them to file

Tags: python-3.x

I have to take the user's name, age and height as input and write them to a file using this format. name,age,height.
I can do with single input but can't figure out with multiple input's. here's what I tried.

```
name=input("enter name: ")
age=int(input("enter age"))
height=int(input("enter height"))
text_file = open('file_name', 'w')
text_file.write(name, '\n', age, '\n', height)
text_file.close()
```

But this gives an error, write() takes exactly one argument.

Comment: as its says, only one arguemnt is allowed. Hint: Concatenate your strings.

Comment: @scharette: the moment I posted this question, I realized my mistake. I spent 20 mins on this simple query. I have added the correct answer. Please mark it an answer it if it is correct. and thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh I got it myself. Mistake was in the write() function.
Here, is the correct statement:

```
text_file.write(str(name)+ str(age) +str(height))
```

or

```
text_file.write(str(name)+ '\n'+ str(age)+ '\n' +str(height))
```

I placed comma instead of '+'. That's why the error.

Thank You all for your inputs.